# Module status keeps running after it has been disabled

Tags: apache2

I rebooted my linux machine and started noticing these odd requests in my Apache access log.

```
::1 - - [16/Dec/2020:21:28:54 -0500] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 404 147 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
::1 - - [16/Dec/2020:21:29:07 -0500] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 404 147 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
::1 - - [16/Dec/2020:21:29:20 -0500] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 404 147 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
::1 - - [16/Dec/2020:21:29:26 -0500] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 404 147 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
::1 - - [16/Dec/2020:21:29:42 -0500] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 404 147 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
::1 - - [16/Dec/2020:21:29:58 -0500] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 404 147 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
```

I did some research on how to disable these requests and discovered they are part of a Apache module called "status". I disabled it, it when I run `a2dismod status` it appears to be disabled:

`Module status already disabled`

How can I get these requests to stop other than blocking them? I'd rather not have my access log filled with garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SetEnvIf:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/server-status?auto$" dontlog
```

More details here:
https://www.howtoforge.com/setenvif_apache2

Or you can find why you have requests and disactivate it. Maybe a monitoring system ?

Comment: I can't exactly find the root cause of it, but I may be Netdata, which is quite tricky to uninstall. Thanks!